# SQL Check Letter

Tags: t-sql, sql-update, case

I am trying to apply a Red / Amber / Green logic put in place for reporting purposes.

COLUMN_NAME will have a string of three characters with combinations of the letters 'R', 'A' and 'G.

I am trying to apply the logic:
If COLUMN_NAME contains 'R' THEN MAJOR_ISSUE
If Column COntains 'A' and NOT 'R' THEN MINOR_ISSUE
ELSE OK

Can you please tell me how I can ammend the SQL Update statement below to achieve this?

```
UPDATE DBO.TABLE_NAME
SET [COLUMN_RESULT] = 
(
CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%R%'THEN 'MAJOR_ISSUE'

  WHEN  COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%A%' ***AND NOT LIKE %R%*** THEN 'MINOR ISSUE'

 ELSE 'OK'
 END
 )
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND` is a logical operator, you need two complete boolean expressions on either side.

- `boolean AND boolean`

`LIKE` is a boolean operator, which needs a string on either side.

- `string LIKE string`

So...

```
WHEN COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%A%' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE '%R%' THEN 'MINOR ISSUE'
```

Or, with brackets to make it more obvious...

```
WHEN (COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%A%') AND (COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE '%R%') THEN 'MINOR ISSUE'
```

Answer (score 0):

A [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) expression *checks* the conditions in order, so you don't need to check for conditions that have already been processed:

```
update DBO.Table_Name
  set Column_Result = case
    when Column_Name like '%R%' then 'MAJOR_ISSUE'
    -- At this point   Column_Name   cannot contain an 'R'.
    when Column_Name like '%A%' then 'MINOR_ISSUE'
    else 'OK' end;
```

Note that there have been various issues where `case` *evaluates* expressions without short-circuiting, e.g. a divide-by-zero might occur when you have already checked for a zero value because the expressions are being evaluated out-of-order.